# Upload PDF and other files from the Front-End

Tags: uploads, front-end, user-access, pdf, wp-filesystem

I am trying to create a medical website, where logged-in doctors can actually upload pdfs and other files (such as jpg) from the front-end in posts. Then, after reloading the page, the uploaded files should be retrieved within the same post, so other users can easily find the info, without any access to the back-end whatsoever.

Can this be done in WP?

Thanks in advance!

Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in WordPress. Check out http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/ for some code examples.

You will have to modify the logic to suit your needs of course, but the above link should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Seems well explained, I'll definitely try it out. I thought it'd be easier achieving this (I'm not coding-savvy at all) but it might be time to get cracking with creating custom plugins. Cheers!